# How to update a file field in Drupal 7

Tags: file, drupal, field

In hook_user_update I'm retrieving a facebook profile pic and saving a record in the file_managed table. That much is going well.  But I also want to save a record for a file field attached to the user entity.  Normally what I do in these hooks is assign the values to $edit['field_something'], and I think that's the correct way to do this.  That has always worked for other field types, but it is not working for the file field.  You can see toward the end of the function where I dump the vars to confirm that I have something suitable to assign to $edit['field_something'] -- at least, I think it's suitable.  I get no errors, but no record is created in the field_data_field_image table.  What am I missing?  Thank you!

```
/**
 *  Implementation of hook_user_update().
 *  
 */
function hifb_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {

  if (empty($account->field_image['und'])) {

    $fbid = $edit['field_facebook_id']['und'][0]['value'];

    if (!empty($fbid)) {

      $url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?type=large';

      if ($file_contents = file_get_contents($url)) {

        $size = getimagesize($url);
        $ext = image_type_to_extension($size[2]); 
        $filename = 'fb_' . $fbid . '_u_' . $account->uid . $ext;

        $uri = file_default_scheme() . '://' . $filename;

        // Saves the file to the default files directory and creates the record in files_managed table.
        $file = file_save_data($file_contents, $uri, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);

        //var_dump($file); die;
        /* Here's an example from the var_dump: object(stdClass)#120 (8) { ["fid"]=> string(3) "576" ["uri"]=> string(30) "public://fb_767816596_u_1.jpeg" ["filename"]=> string(21) "fb_767816596_u_1.jpeg" ["filemime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["uid"]=> string(1) "1" ["status"]=> int(1) ["timestamp"]=> int(1339686244) ["filesize"]=> int(2919) } */

        // Creates record in field_data_field_image table??
        $edit['field_image']['und'][0] = (array)$file;

      }
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason it doesn't work is because in hook_user_update, the update has already occurred.  So setting a value for $edit has no effect.  The same code that I posted in the question works fine in hook_user_presave.